# How do I share files with a linux virtual machine from a Win 7 desktop

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtual-machine, webserver

I have a Win7 deskptop (host) and want to run a linux virtual machine; but I want that linux virtual machine to be able to access a directory on the host machine (in this case, to serve a web directory).

What virtual machine software would you recommend for this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close because the answer can hardly answered in it's current form. *Every* VM does support sharing folders on at least two ways, so all you get as answers would be *personal opinions* about what's the best VM.

Answer (score 3):

You have not mentioned which virtualization application you will be using to set up the virtual machine. With VMware for example, you are given the option to select a folder on the host machine to be used a shareable resource/folder between the host and the guest. For purposes that include moving files back and forth easily between the host and the guest, this shared folder approach works really well.

Answer (score 2):

you have multiple choices, such as VMware workstation or VirtualBox.

VMware : downloads.vmware.com/d/info/desktop_downloads/vmware_workstation/7_0

VirtuaBox : www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads